# Gameplay questions within scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

(Prompted by [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54185/question-about-the-war-game-grand-battle).)

Games are **big** on Android. They're a [huge category on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME), and the Play Store app shows Games at the same level as Apps (as well as Movies & TV, Music, Books, and Magazines).

There have been *very few* [games](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) questions asked here, and the vast majority of those have been about trying to get a game to run on a particular device or to save/export the save-game data to reload after a factory reset or onto another device. (And, frankly, a good bunch of mis-tagged questions that are only about "games" insofar as the app the person is trying to work with happens to be a game, but I digress.)

However, our help center makes no mention of games and questions about gameplay, either that they are or are not on-topic. I think we should rectify that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My opinion is that questions which are purely about gameplay ("How do I beat level 5 in Inexplicably Popular Social Game-of-the-Month?") should go to [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com). They simply aren't about Android the OS, even if the title is platform exclusive.

Configuring hardware or something to work with a game could be OS dependent - something like "How can I set up a Bluetooth controller for my Android device?" as an example - and those seem okay, but gameplay questions should be directed to...well, gamers. We may have gamers here, but it's just not our purpose.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: Should we add Arqade to the default migration paths? We have the room for a new entry, but probably not the volume to justify it.

Comment: And, shouldn't we explicitly add this to our list of off-topic topics?

Comment: We can't add it ourselves, and definitely don't have the volume.  I'm not sure we need to make explicit mention of it either, unless it's going to be an issue.

Comment: Unless we get a lot more such questions in future, I'd say just shut the questions as off-topic and direct people to go ask a Arqade.

Comment: Well, Moderators can migrate a question anywhere. If we happen to get an excellent question in the wrong place, we should ask for it to be migrated.